# How can I return an char array from a function using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am trying to write a function that reads a text file and puts every words of this text into an array with dynamic allocation so that this array is not over-sized.

I managed to write a working function that creates an array with every words (i.e arr[0] = "bla", arr[1] = "bla", ...) but I can't return this array, so i can use it in my main().

```c
char* toArray(char *filename) {
  int words = countWords(filename); // this function returns the number of words in the file
  char *arr[words]; 
  int cur_size = 0;
  int i;

  FILE *file;
  file = fopen(filename, "r");

  for(int i = 0; i < words; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%*s%n", &cur_size);
    arr[i] = malloc( (cur_size+1) * sizeof(char));
  }
  fclose(file);

  file = fopen(filename, "r");
  for (i = 0; i < words; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%s", arr[i]);
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
  fclose(file);

  return arr; // not sure if this is how i should return it
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char *arr = toArray("file.txt");
  printf("%s", arr[0]); 

  return 0;
}
```

I expected

```c
 printf("%s", arr[0])
```

to print the first word of my file.

but instead i get this error :
format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=] printf("%s\n", arr[0]);

I guess i made a mistake in my function ?

Comment: Even if you allocate the elements in the array `arr` dynamically, the array `arr` *itself* is not allocated dynamically. Returning it will return a pointer to a local variable, a local variable which will cease to exist immediately once the function returns. What's more, you have an array of pointers, which will never be equal to the type `char *`, but with dynamic allocation could be of the type`char **`.

Comment: So, if i allocate dynamically my arr itself like this
char *arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfChar))
it should be better ?

Comment: I allocated my memory to my `arr` like this now : 
      `char *arr = malloc(numberOfChar*sizeof(char));`  
but now i got issues with my elements allocation :  
    `arr[i] = malloc( (cur_size + 1) * sizeof(char))`  
assignement makes integer from pointer without a cast
i don't know why this happens

Comment: What you seem to want is an array of strings. A "string" can be seen as a`char *`. And array can be seen as a pointer to its (first) element. So if you have an array of `char *` you need a pointer to `char *` which turns out to be a `char **`. Now for how to allocate it, you're part-ways there with the code you show in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is local, we need to declare it dynamically. Please try below sample code.

```
char **arr = NULL;
arr = (char**)malloc(words*sizeof(char*))
/* then use it */
return arr;
```

Comment: I tried it but the return type of `arr` seems to be wrong.

i got "return from incompatible pointer type return `arr` "

should i return `*arr` instead ? since the array  is composed of strings which are `*char`

Comment: you need to change function return type to char**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your answers !
I managed to make it work.

I changed my function return type to `char**`
I allocated memory dynamically to my array like this:
`arr = (char **)malloc(words*sizeof(char));`

and then it worked in my main when I delcared 
`char **arr = toArray("file.txt");`

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
 char *arr = toArray("file.txt");
```

In this case, `arr` is a string, and not an array of strings! Therefore, `arr[0]`  is just a single char, and not a string. And a single char is basically treated like an int.

Comment: This is only part of the problem. OP is attempting to return an array of strings, and fixing their `main` routine to handle one string will not accomplish that.

Comment: Entering text as answers is for answers, not hints.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't get where i make it wrong in my function.  
Is my array type definition the problem ? Or is it just the way i'm allocating memory ?